# Getting current logged_in user in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm developping a blog with Django, and I'd like my posts to be related to their author. I've created an author field in my Blog model class, which is a ForeignKey pointing on a User object. Problem is, South database migration django tool asks me for a default value to give to it. Actually, I'd like it to be the id of the logged in user who edited the post, but can't see how to make it. Any idea?

This is my Blog model class:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
PUBLISHING_STATUS = (
    ('P', 'Published'),
    ('D', 'Draft'),
    ('AA', 'Awaiting Approval'),
    )
title = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=160, unique=True)
header_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/uploaded', max_length=256, null=True)
body = models.TextField()
author = models.ForeignKey(User)
status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=PUBLISHING_STATUS, null=True)
posted = models.DateTimeField('date posted')
category = models.ForeignKey('blog.Category')
tags = models.ManyToManyField('blog.Tags')

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return '/blog/%s/view_post' % self.slug
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the field to be required you will have to set a default value when migrating. For the reason you don't have stored any data anywhere about who created the post, you ca only set it to a specific user, which in this case probably should be your administrator user!

You could then edit the posts in the admin and set them to the correct author, if necessary!

If you are looking for a way to auto-populate the field upon saving a new post in the admin, you have to override the `save_model` method on your `ModelAdmin`:

```
class BlogPostAdmin(model_admin):   

    def save_model(self, request, instance, form, change):
        user = request.user 
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        if not change or not instance.author:
            instance.author = user
        instance.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return instance
```

Answer (score 1):

> Problem is, South database migration django tool asks me for a default value to give to it.

Why?  Because you have old data that you're trying to preserve?  Perhaps you shouldn't be trying to keep any old data.

> Actually, I'd like it to be the id of the logged in user who edited the post, but can't see how to make it. Any idea?

That's what view functions are for.  You don't do this in the model.  You do this in the view function that handles the Form.

Comment: So you think I should set default value to "1" and rather set default author choice to the current logged in user in the post edition form?

Comment: @oleiade: You cannot set the default value to some random number.  It's either `None` or it's the exact right User who actually owns the Blog posting.  You can't pick a random value like `1` unless you want user number 1 to own all the blog postings (which makes no sense at all.)

Answer (score 0):

You should do this as a two step process.  First, do a schema migration with any default value to create the new structure.  Then, do a data migration to update the author column with the correct value from the user table.