# Django: How to save current username to the database

Tags: django

I'm a new Django (1.3) user and I'm setting up the typical blog/article application.  I have a model in which I'd like to save the current username (to see who created the article).  I've implemented [advice on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470105/getting-current-logged-in-user-in-django), but my code crashes the server with the message: "NameError: name 'User' is not defined".  Here's my model:

```
from django.db import models

class Resort(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    description = models.TextField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    ski_hire = models.TextField()
    weather = models.TextField()
    piste_map = models.TextField()
    webcam = models.TextField()
    snow = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I have a sneaking suspicion that I need to override the save method in admin.py, but I'm not sure how to do this.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You should show the code that actually does the operation and causes the error, plus the traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you import user from `django.contrib.auth.models` in your models.py when using User in a foreign key.

In your admin.py you can use [save_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model):

```
class ResortAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.author = request.user
        obj.save()
```

Comment: I had to drop the tables and run syncdb, but this worked perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You should import User class before assignment?

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```